# CSS - Display:block getting put by default

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm extremely new in the programming world, learning by myself. I've been able to create 2 basic website mockups, but on the 3rd one, I'm having an issue I haven't encountered before.

I'm simply trying to align a container `Div` to the center of the page but it refuses to, when using Chrome's inspect tool it shows a `display:block` preventing to alignment of the items. I have no idea where that block is coming from.

HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="main-container">
     <div id="upper-text">
         Hello
     </div>

     <div id="lower-text">
         <div class="subcontainer">
             <div class=text>Lom ipsum dolo</div>
         </div>

         <div class="subcontainer">
             <div class=text>Lom ipsum dolo</div>
         </div>
     </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#main-container {
   max-width: 980px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   align-items: center;
}
```

I searched on the internet but couldn't find a related issue. Maybe in too new for that.

The code for the current site I'm working on is way longer and this section is the first one presenting this issue. I opened a clean VS Studio file and wrote only the code I'm posting here, with the same results.

Comment: All elements have default CSS properties. If you want a different one you have to specify it. For example, you could set `display: inline-block` and a width on your div if you want to center it.

Comment: You want to align all main-container content horizontally center correct ?

Comment: Also if you want align-items property to work in your page then you need to add display: flex property.

Comment: DIVs are block elements by default, SPANS are inline by default. Both can be changed by CSS if desired.

Answer (score -2):

The "display" property defaults to "block". To center a block with "display: block" you can set the "margin" property to "auto" for the side margins.

The "align-items" property is used in conjunction with the "display" property in the "flex" value. "flex" is set for the parent block, and "align-items" will affect children. Learn in more detail how to work with flexbox, for example, here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Your first sentence is not correct: The "display" property for example defaults to "inline" for `span`, `img` or `a` elements (and others)